# custom UItableView not displaying correctly on ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made a custom `UITableViewCell` and when I display it, i have this result (I'm running xcode 6 and iOS 8 beta 1 on an iPhone 5.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oswn.png

And when I rotate my device, then rotate back to portrait, everything becomes correct.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlICk.png

Note that when I was using xcode 5 to compile my app, I had no problems.

Code used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
BGTCoursCell1 *cell = (BGTCoursCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
NSArray  *nib = [[NSBundle  mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BGTCoursCell1" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];

if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
   BGTCours *cours = [[currentDay coursMatin] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.matiereLabel.text = [cours matiere];
    cell.salleLabel.text = [cours salle];
    cell.heureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"De %@ à %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[cours beginDate]], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[cours endDate]]];
}
else
{
   BGTCours *cours = [[currentDay coursAprem] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.matiereLabel.text = [cours matiere];
    cell.salleLabel.text = [cours salle];
    cell.heureLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"De %@ à %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[cours beginDate]], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[cours endDate]]];
}
return cell;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to return a `CGFloat` from the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` . The error you are seeing will appear if you return a float from the same method:

```
//causes the bug
-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //...
}

//fixes the bug
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return tableView.rowHeight; // whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks fixed my issue iOS 8 beta 5

Comment: Nice. Fixed me on iOS 8 beta 5 as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Fixed for me on ios8 beta5

Comment: This didn't work for me for the released version of iOS8

Comment: This didn't work for me either with the released version of iOS8, but frankish answer did.

Answer (score 2):

This question has an accepted answer, but I have the same problem which was not fixed by the accepted answer which tells us to change `float` to `CGFloat`.

I found out that people who has code based on table's `rowHeight` may have this problem too. In iOS8 it is important to look at `estimatedRowHeight` not just `rowHeight`.

As I was using these variables in my programmatically generated `UITableView`, fixing those variables solved the problem.

Comment: I also had to create my own `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late to the party but I've encountered exactly same problem with iOS 8 beta 2 and xCode 6 beta 2 today(26-June-2014), I see they still haven't fixed the bug.

There's also another bug with xCode 6 beta, that is my app can no request the GPS location properly - it simply won't ask for the permission. This is also solved by switching back to xCode 5. I think at the moment is more viable to use xCode 5 to build and test your app.

Answer (score 0):

try reusing the cell, like, change:

```
BGTCoursCell1 *cell = (BGTCoursCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
NSArray  *nib = [[NSBundle  mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BGTCoursCell1" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

to

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellNib = @"BGTCoursCell1";

BGTCoursCell1 *cell = (BGTCoursCell1 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if( cell == nil ) {
    NSArray  *nib = [[NSBundle  mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

...
return cell;
```

Comment: I've got the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

i had a slightly similar problem and fixed it by using
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, but just hides the problem: the content you want to show is no longer visible as it is cut. (If you don't show anything and if your font is small you may not see the difference)