# UITableViewCell not dynamically resizing using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to dynamically resize my UITableView Cells in swift:

[image]

Above is my cell setup for the smallest possible screen size (iPhone 4). The green view (an image) will enlarge if the screen width increases and retain its aspect ratio. It's pinned to the top, leading edge trading edge and aspect ratio enabled. The label below is centered horizontally. The top pinned to the bottom of the image and the height and width fixed.

I have this code in viewDidLoad:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 262
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

If I run the app I get the warning:

*Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.* The cell is also the wrong size only about 25pts in height. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First if all, check out this link. You may be missing an overload:

[custom UItableView not displaying correctly on ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110341/custom-uitableview-not-displaying-correctly-on-ios8)

Second, look at your constraints again. Just for the vertical dimension, you've set the distance from the image to the top, from the image to the label, and from the label to the bottom.

The size of the label will be given by the text.

But the size of the image is uncertain. You have a leading constraint and an aspect ratio, but how does that specify a size?

Basically if you were to render this yourself, would you have enough information to do it?

Comment: For the image I have a leading and trailing constraint. So the size will be specified based on the width of the screen

Answer (score 0):

- Try add constraint: label's bottom to cell's bottom
- Remove label's fix height.

Hope this can help.